# How to change focus style color? (watchOS 2)

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

Is there any way to change color of focus style in WKInterfacePicker? (default: greenColor)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set WKInterfacePicker color (text or outline)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923649/set-wkinterfacepicker-color-text-or-outline)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't change the colour of focus style.